# Can't save mongoid hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, mongoid

I have a mongoid object

`@tran = Translations.where({:_id => params[:id]})[0]`

The object `@tran` has a array of hashes at `@tran[:translations]`

I tried changing the value of a hash in the array like so:

`@tran[:translations][0]['rated'] = (@tran[:translations][0]['rated']+1)`

and I did a `@tran.save`

But the value does not seem to be updated.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS, Here's the value of `@tran[:translations]` : `[{"value":"hello3","rating":100,"rated":0}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@tran = Translation.find params[:id]
```

You can use this line ->

```
@tran.update_attributes(:rated => @tran.rated+1)
```

Or this line ->

```
@tran.rated += 1
@tran.save
```